# Cannot create connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-12560

I am a new user in Oracle. In Oracle SQL Developer, whenever I want to create a new connection and fill the "New Database Connection" form, it gives me this error: -

```
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

Please Help.

Comment: Is your database open? This error can be seen when the database is not started.

Comment: I'll also post this question: do you have the Oracle Client software installed and thus an %oracle_home%/Network/Admin/tnsnames.ora file?  If not, you can simply do a connection type of basic and avoid the tnsnames files altogether; or install the ora client and go from there.

Comment: @Ollie My database has already started.

Comment: @Mansoor Gee, is your listener started too?

Comment: @Ollie How can I check this that listener has started?

Comment: See my answer from yesterday. At the command prompt type: lsnrctl start. You can check the status with lsnrctl status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more to my comment on the question...

Ensure your database is open (has been started up).

1. Start all oracle services for your database
2. Start the databases listener (lsnrctl start)
3. Startup your database instance (startup open <`database_name`>)

Also, ensure the database you are trying to connect to has an entry in the `tnsnames.ora` file your SQL Developer is using (depending upon your setup you may have a `tnsnames.ora` for both your oracle client and database software if they are on the same physical hardware like your PC or laptop).

Comment: Last I checked sql developer doesn't need a tnsnames.ora

Comment: It doesn't need one, but it can reference one. Having no information about the OP's environment i'm trying to cover a range of options.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced that kinda problem also and I've tried stop all of oracle services and start it again. But unsuccessful. Eventually, I've needed to install Oracle again which can solve this problem.

Comment: But I don't need to re-install Oracle. There must be some a solution without re-installing it.